# Call JS function from code behind C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, function

I have a function onRowClick called RowClick and is working fine. I am trying to move it to a button and call the function from the code behind. For some reason is not triggering the function.. Anyone knows why and how I can fix this?

aspx.cs

```
  if (e.CommandName == "Addvoucher")
            {

               GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

            var id = item.GetDataKeyValue("RowID");

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "mykey", "RowClick("+id+");", true);

            }
```

aspx

```
  <script>
        var popUpObj;
        function RowClick(sender, eventArgs) {
            var filterId = eventArgs.getDataKeyValue('RowID');


            popUpObj = window.open("voucher.aspx?param=" + filterId + "",
             "ModalPopUp",
             "toolbar=no," +
             "scrollbars=no," +
             "location=no," +
             "statusbar=no," +
             "menubar=no," +
             "resizable=0," +
             "width=530," +
             "height=500," +
             "left = 450," +
             "top=130" 
            );
             popUpObj.focus();
             LoadModalDiv();


         }


     function LoadModalDiv()
     {
         var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
         bcgDiv.style.display="block";
     }

     function HideModalDiv() {
         var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
         bcgDiv.style.display = "none";
     }

     </script>
```

IN page voucher.aspx

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">

             function OnClose() {

                 if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
                     window.opener.location.reload(); //refreshing parent when popup close
                     // window.opener.HideModalDiv();
                 }

                 //if (window.closed==true) window.open("~/routedoc.aspx");
             }
             window.onunload = OnClose;

    </script>
```

Comment: Change RegisterStartupScript to RegisterClientScriptBlock.

Comment: Check browser console to see if there is any error ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataKeyValue' of undefined

Comment: This is because eventAgrs is undefined because you haven't passed these arguments to the function when you are calling it from code behind.

Comment: Now just pass id as parameter and receive it as a normal parameter and use it directly in your js function. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your js function like this

```
function RowClick(filterId) {

popUpObj = window.open("voucher.aspx?param=" + filterId + "",
         "ModalPopUp",
         "toolbar=no," +
         "scrollbars=no," +
         "location=no," +
         "statusbar=no," +
         "menubar=no," +
         "resizable=0," +
         "width=530," +
         "height=500," +
         "left = 450," +
         "top=130" 
        );
         popUpObj.focus();
         LoadModalDiv();


     }
```

There is no need of this line now `var filterId = eventArgs.getDataKeyValue('RowID');` Now you can directly use the parameter `filterId` in your js function.

Comment: emm yeah now is working but when i press the Close(X) the window does not close

Comment: I have just included the function RowClick in my answer you need other two functions also which i haven't included other functions because other functions will remain same.

Comment: Yes i didnt change anything else except the change you have told me and now i have this problem. I have update my code on question have a look

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
browserLink:37 Setting 'XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials' for synchronous requests is deprecated.

Comment: And why you want to reload the parent page on close of child page ?

Comment: As the error says that it is deprecated so i guess you can't do that you may be running latest version of browser. Check it on another browser.

Answer (score 1):

Calling JavaScript function on code behind i.e. On Page_Load

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ", true);
```

If you have `UpdatePanel` there then try like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:FUNCTIONNAME(); ", true);
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataKeyValue' of undefined

Comment: `getDataKeyValue` ??.  Post your code where u using getDataKeyValue ?

Comment: is the first line on script

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling `RowClick()` and in your code you are calling the second parameter `eventArgs` and actually it's an `undefined` value.

Make sure you pass the correct parameters.

Since you just calling a javscript function then I would recommend to just on the grid row data bound just assign the value to an anchor `a` tag or a button to just call the javascript.

Comment: Can i call the function from here?        <telerik:GridButtonColumn Text="Add Voucher" UniqueName="Addvoucher"  HeaderText="Addvoucher" CommandName="Addvoucher" >
                     </telerik:GridButtonColumn>

Comment: No, just add a template column then add a link then on the grid row databound event find that link and update the href with `javascript:RowClick(123)` assuming 123 is ur id

Comment: I have try your way and i cant pass the RowID as parameter. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not passing any arguments for that js function from server side but you are getting data key value in client function as in your edited question pass row id from server side and change the client side function as below,

```
function RowClick(rowId)
{ 
  // use rowId
  popUpObj = window.open("voucher.aspx?param=" + rowId + "",
}
```